# Regex used to check if naming convention is valid

Tags: java, regex

I've been trying to figure out a regex statement for this

```
hello_123.123.123.anything123_-
```

Rules:

`hello_123.123.123` (This part is mandatory, there must be a-z and underscore and three sets of numbers, seperated by dots)

`.anything123_-` (That is freeform, it must start with a dot, then any number, any letter and as many dashes or underscores are allowed.)

So far I have

```
[a-zA-Z]+_(\d+\.*){3}
```

But the issue is that the dot recurs a third time when its not needed and am unsure how to force the last dot to only be valid if there is trailing values

Now I have

```
([a-zA-Z]+_)(\d+\.+){2}(\d+)
```

It's messy and forced but works partially

Comment: What kind of regexes are you using?  Perl?  If you want to match a literal `.`, you need to escape it with a backslash (so `\.`).

Comment: it will be java, atm am looking for splitting it up into two groups, the first is the mandatory match that has to be matched or it fails, and the second is optional. So far I have this (([a-zA-Z]+_)(\d+\.){2}(\d+){1})(?<=(\.)[\d][\w]+)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
([a-zA-Z]+_(?:\d+\.){2}\d+)(\.[\w_-]+)?
```

[Online test](http://fiddle.re/yx9tg) (Click on "Java")

Comment: That works almost perfectly but dashes are not recognised as valid :(